# Why is performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: not recommended for frequent inter-thread communication

Tags: multithreading, macos, communication

Apple's [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/Multithreading.pdf) states that:

> Although good for occasional
>   communication between threads, you
>   should not use the
>   performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
>   method for time critical or frequent
>   communication between threads.

Which begs the questions: Which is, then, the acceptable method for frequent inter-thread communication, and why is performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: specifically not recommended.

ps: Not waiting until done, naturally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they don’t recommend using that probably is because this has a lot of overhead. Also it works only with threads that have a `NSRunloop` running. It’s really good for updating the UI from a secondary thread though.

For more heavy duty lifting you should use shared memory (with locks or lockless algorithms) for inter-thread-communication. Or even better use something like NSOperationQueue or Grand Central Dispatch and don’t worry about doing the communication and synchronization yourself, if your problem permits that.